# Logic Apps Times Out Due To Long Running Azure Functions Being Called Inside It

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I am currently working on supporting an old application which uses logic apps and azure functions.
The logic apps are on consumption plan and it times out frequently due to long running azure functions which in turn calls ms sql server using EF core.

Now, we don't want to spend much time on development as it will be sunset and migrated so azure durable functions, webhooks, and event bus is not being considered.

Are there any other ways to solve this which requires no major code changes?
**We are planning to move from consumption to standard logic apps to increase the timeout from 2 minutes to 3.9 minutes.**

Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: No matter what you do, there's work.  I reckon the easiest approach would be a webhook, minimal change on the LogicApps side and not overly complicated on the functions side either.  You could change out the Azure Function step to be a webhook and then in the function, all you need to do is process the payload to retrieve the webhook URL and then call that once you're done.  That's my two cents.

Answer (score 1):

I had found one alternative that you can use [until loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-actions-triggers#until-action).
Until loops run until specific condition is true. Until loop requires 200 ok Response from the request. As per [MS-Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-actions-triggers#until-action), it says:

> This loop action definition sends an HTTP request to the specified URL .

As @skin suggested, you can use webhooks, durable functions which does exactly what you need (if development is not concern). And as you said you can change to Standard to increase timeout till 4 min.